# Assignment a value to index of pointer

Tags: c, pointers, variable-assignment

I try to assign a value to the second index of pointer, it gives me a warning

> "[Warning] assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast"

and it doesn't run this program. I wonder, where am I making a mistake?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char *p="John";
    *(p+2)="v";
    printf("%s",p);
}
```

Comment: You know that even if you succeed compiling this it's wrong because writing to string literals is undefined behavior, don't you?

Comment: A pointer does not have an index. Please change your question title to a more clear one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning a pointer to a string literal to an element of another string literal.

First, you need to change the pointer and make it an array, so any modification is legal, this is an example

```
char p[] = "John";
```

then you need to replace `"v"` which is a string literal consisting of two characters `'v'` and `'\0'`, to `'v'` which is the ascii value for the letter `v` as an integer

```
*(p + 2) = 'v';
```

also, this is the third element and not the second, because the first element is `p[0]`.

Comment: Maybe, it's an english name and it's not my native language.

Answer (score 2):

**Firstly**, In your code,

```
 char *p="John";
```

`p` points to a string literal, and attempt to modify a string literal invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Related, `C11`, chapter §6.4.5

> [...] If the program attempts to modify such an array, the behavior is
>   undefined.

If you want to modify , you need an array, like

```
char p[]="John";
```

**Secondly**, `*(p+2)="v";` is wrong, as `""` denotes a *string*, whereas you need a `char` (*Hint: check the type os `*(p+2)`*). Change that to

```
*(p+2)='v';
```

To elaborate the difference, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.4.4.4, for *Character constants*

> An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed
>   in single-quotes, as in `'x'`.

and chapter §6.4.5, *string literals*

> A character string literal is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in
>   double-quotes, as in `"xyz"`.

**Thirdly**, as per the C standards, `void main()` should *at least* be `int main(void)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're making two mistakes.

First, you are attempting to modify the contents of a *string literal*; this invokes *undefined behavior*, meaning any of the following are possible (and considered equally correct): your code may crash, it may run to completion with no issues, it may run to completion but not alter the string literal, it may leave your system in a bad state, etc.  Your compiler may reject the code completely, although I don't know of any compiler that does so.

If you want to be able to modify the contents of a string, then you need to set aside storage for that string, instead of just pointing to a string literal:

```
char p[] = "John"; // copies the contents of the string literal "John" to p
                   // p is sized automatically based on the length of the
                   // string literal
```

Here's a hypothetical memory map showing the result of that declaration and initialization:

```
Address            Item            0x00  0x01  0x02  0x03
-------            ----            ----  ----  ----  ----
0x8000             "John"           'J'   'o'   'h'   'n'
0x8004                             0x00  0x??   0x?? 0x??  // 0x?? represents a random byte value
...
0xfffdc100         p                'J'   'o'   'h'   'n'
0xfffdc104                         0x00  0x??  0x??  0x??
```

The string literal that lives at `0x8000` should not be modified; the string that lives in `p` at `0xfffdc100` may be modified (although the buffer will only have enough space to store up to a 4-character string).

Your second mistake (and the one causing the compiler to complain) is in this line:

```
*(p+2)="v";
```

The expression `"v"` is a string literal and has type "2-element array of `char`"; since it's not the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, the type "decays" to "pointer to `char`", and the value of the expression is the address of the string literal `"v"`.

The expression `*(p + 2)` has type `char` (it resolves to a single character value), which is an integral type, not a pointer type.  You cannot assign pointer values to non-pointer objects.

You can easily fix that by changing that line to

```
*(p + 2) = 'v'; // note single quote vs double quote
```

This time, instead of trying to assign the address of a string literal to `p[2]`, you're assigning the value of a single character.